# Como puedo solucionar este problema?

Tags: asp.net, mvc, devexpress

He creado un proyecto MVC 5, lo tengo en un dominio en https://www.smarterasp.net
El problema es que cuando quiero loggearme me manda el msj que compartire en la captura de pantalla.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otro lado, lo alojo en https://www.smarterasp.net y me manda el msj que compartire en esta otra imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías pegar el mensaje completo de la validación?

Comment: No lo puedo poner completo como texto no me deja copiar, lo puse como una respuesta, creo que los moderadores la borraran, si puedes verla antes porfa

Comment: No creo que sirva, Abre las developer tools y revisa los mensajes de red a ver que encuentras, así díficil que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Comment: Me puedes ayudar por correo o skype y te mando las credenciales para que puedas ver el error?

Comment: Así no funciona StackOverflow, te recomiendo que leas como realizar preguntas correctas para poder recibir respuestas https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3274/obteniendo-respuestas?cb=1